# What is this spongy material?

Tags: emc, repair, cooling

[image]
[image]

Hi, while I am tring to repair electronic circuit. I'm encountering this sponge. I wonder what is this sponge? and can I find out what it is used for. I often see this in sensitive circuits like in laptop board and near to cooling parts. Adheres on cooler materials

Comment: EMC gasket. Search for laird tech.

Comment: It's basically a fancy version of a spring engineered to be more conductive or lighter (or in some instances simply fancier/trendier/fashionable) than a simple spring contact

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is some kind of soft-open-cell foam, wrapped in conductive tape, to ensure a good grounding and shielding contact between pieces. The foam may or may not have large amounts of carbon particles in it to make the foam itself conductive.

Answer (score 5):

As established this is an EMC foam gasket. It is commonly applied to lids of stainless steel enclosures and used for various grounding practices to improve ground connections or to provide a faraday cage for the blocking of electromagnetic fields.